# window resize not working after class hidden removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a intro screen using CSS animations and velocity with a setTimeout function that does fadeOut and addClass hidden. At the same time it also does a fadeIn with removeClass hidden on the SVG full screen image. The issue is that when the SVG image loads, its not full screen. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the SVG is loading at the same time the intro is running. Once you resize the window the SVG goes full screen. I'm not sure what route is the best way to fix this, I have a feeling im going about doing the intro animation the wrong way. Please help! Here is the code below, i also have a [codepen.io here.](https://codepen.io/robbiecren07/pen/VwYWJmK)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".intro-animation .left")
    .delay(400)
    .velocity({ width: 0 }, 1200);
   $(".intro-animation .right")
    .delay(1500)
    .velocity({ width: 0 }, 1200);

   setTimeout(function(){
     $(".intro-animation").fadeOut("slow", function() {
         $(this).addClass("intro-hidden");
     });
       $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
           $(this).removeClass("intro-hidden");
       });
   },3000)
 });
// DRAW SVG MASK /////////////////////////////
var svg = document.querySelector("#svg__bg");
var tl = new TimelineMax({onUpdate:onUpdate});
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
var counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
var ratio = 0.5625;

TweenMax.set("#instructions, #dial", {xPercent: -50});

tl.to("#masker", 2, {attr:{r:2400}, ease:Power2.easeIn});
tl.reversed(true);

function mouseHandler() {
  tl.reversed(!tl.reversed());
}

function getPoint(evt){
  pt.x = evt.clientX;
  pt.y = evt.clientY;
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function mouseMove(evt) {
  var newPoint = getPoint(evt);
  TweenMax.set("#dot", {attr:{cx:newPoint.x, cy:newPoint.y}});
  TweenMax.to("#ring, #masker", 0.88, {attr:{cx:newPoint.x, cy:newPoint.y}, ease:Power2.easeOut});
 }

function onUpdate() {
  var prog = (tl.progress() * 100);
  counter.textContent = prog.toFixed();
}

function newSize() {
  var w = window.innerWidth ;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  if (w > h * (16/9) ) {
    TweenMax.set("#svg__bg", { attr: { width: w, height: w * ratio } });
  } else {
    TweenMax.set("#svg__bg", { attr: { width: h / ratio, height: h } });
  }
  var data = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  TweenMax.set("#svg__bg", {x:w/2 - data.width/2});
  TweenMax.set("#svg__bg", {y:h/2 - data.height/2});
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);

newSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", newSize);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700&display=swap');

body {
 min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1F242D;
 cursor: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.intro-hidden {
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.intro-animation {
    background-color: #2d5a87;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .intro-animation .left, .intro-animation .right {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .intro-animation .left {
    background: #5B6076;
    right: 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .intro-animation .right {
    background: #66BBDE;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .intro-animation .intro-logo {
    width: 470px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .intro-animation .box {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #0074D9;
    color: #fff;
   font-family: 'MonumentExtended-Regular';
    font-size: 1.5em;
   line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 3;
    animation: test1 3s;
  }
  .intro-animation .box:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -10px; bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    animation: expand1 3s;
  }

  .intro-animation .text {
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
   font-family: 'MonumentExtended-Regular';
    font-size: 1.5em;
   line-height: 60px;
    animation: fade1 3.5s;
  }

  @keyframes expand1 {
    0% { height: 0; }
    40% { height: 0; }
    60% { height: 80%; }
  }

  @keyframes test1 {
    0% { transform: scale(0);  left: 39%; }
    40% { transform: scale(1);  left: 39%;}
    60% { transform: scale(1);  left: 39%;}
    100% { left: 0%; }
  }

  @keyframes fade1 {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    65% { opacity: 0; padding-left: 40px; }
    100% { opacity: 1; padding-left: 80px; }
  }
.intro-svg {
 position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
 height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.loaded .intro-svg {
 animation-name: fadeInDown;
 animation-duration: 2.5s;
 animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.svg__container {
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg__image {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 cursor: none;
}
#instructions {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px;
  top: 1em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  right: 1em;
  cursor: none;
  padding-top: 80px;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#instructions p {
  margin-top:0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #FFF;
}
#dial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
.text-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: none;
  z-index:2;
}
.impact-text {
  font-size: 7em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-animation">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>

  <div class="intro-logo">
    <div class="box">RC</div>
    <div class="text">
      <span class="first">Robbie</span>
      <span class="second">Crenshaw</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay" class="intro-hidden">
<div class="intro-svg">
          <div class="svg__container">
            <svg id="svg__bg" class="svg__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1600 900">
              <defs>
                <radialGradient id="mask-gradient">
                  <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" />
                </radialGradient>
                  <mask id="the-mask">
                    <circle id="masker" r="250" fill="url(#mask-gradient)" cx="800" cy="450">
                    </circle>
                  </mask>
                  <mask id="mask-text" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0">
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-1" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" x="10.1%" y="42%">A</text>
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-2" fill="white" x="10%" y="55%">Digital</text>
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-3" fill="white" x="10%" y="68%">Designer</text>
                  </mask>
              </defs>
                <image id="lines" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/1TQRj56.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                <g id="mask-reveal" mask="url(#the-mask)">
                  <image id="regular" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/7VtEKv3.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                </g>
                <g mask="url(#mask-text)">
                  <image id="text-before" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/7VtEKv3.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                </g>
                <circle id="ring" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#D74A53" stroke-width="2" cx="800" cy="450" />
                <circle id="dot" r="4" fill="#D74A53" cx="800" cy="450"/>
            </svg>

            <div id="instructions">
              <svg id="dial" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <text transform="translate(55 56)" text-anchor="start" font-size="12" fill="#fff">%</text>
                <text id="counter" transform="translate(55 56)" text-anchor="end" font-size="12" fill="#fff">0</text>
              </svg>
              <p>Hold the mouse button,</p><p>for something amazing!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just calling `newSize` at an inappropriate time,calling it

```
   setTimeout(function(){
     $(".intro-animation").fadeOut("slow", function() {
         newSize();                                    // <- Here
         $(this).addClass("intro-hidden");
     });
       $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
           $(this).removeClass("intro-hidden");
       });
   },3000)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need also declare newsize() in $(window). Hopefully, this can help.

```
// initial state
newSize();
// on resize
$(window).on('resize', newSize);
```

or

```
// Attaching the event listener function to window's resize event
window.addEventListener("resize", newSize);

// Calling the function for the first time
newSize();
```

Comment: I already have this at the bottom of the JS, Do you mean to add it inside my setTimeout?